# I stop inserting data after multiple executing in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have to generate data by inserting to the table, but every time I execute this PS it added new rows to the end of my table, how can I stop inserting data after multiple executing

my code is:

```
DECLARE @CountFID int 
SET @CountFID = (SELECT COUNT(FID) FROM DataFoodView)

INSERT INTO FoodSara_tbl
SELECT FID + (@CountFID) , Fname, Ftype, Fcount ,FoodDate , Fregion, Fdescription
FROM dbo.DataFoodView
ORDER BY FoodDate

INSERT INTO FoodSara_tbl
SELECT FID + 2*(@CountFID), Fname, Ftype, Fcount ,FoodDate , Fregion, Fdescription
FROM dbo.DataFoodView
ORDER BY FoodDate
```

PS: I don't want to use trigger

Comment: you are using insert command so why not you get new record ?

Comment: I mean just one time , when ever I execute my whole query, it inserts

Comment: @SaraMoradi . . . Don't run the code multiple times.  Just insert the data you want once.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do and why do you have two `insert` statements?

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question well, you may need to use where to check if there is exist in your table:

```
DECLARE @CountFID int 
SET @CountFID = (SELECT COUNT(FID) FROM DataFoodView)
INSERT INTO FoodSara_tbl
SELECT FID + (@CountFID) , Fname, Ftype, Fcount ,FoodDate , Fregion, Fdescription
FROM dbo.DataFoodView
Where FID not in (select FID from FoodSara_tbl )

INSERT INTO FoodSara_tbl
SELECT FID + 2*(@CountFID), Fname, Ftype, Fcount ,FoodDate , Fregion, Fdescription
FROM dbo.DataFoodView
Where FID not in (select FID from FoodSara_tbl )
```

Comment: Kinda it's true, but `Where FID not in (select FID from FoodSara_tbl )` doesn't give me the count of new inserted rows, for example my original table has 20 records, by inserting i have 60 records, but this code give just 20 recods